# Taking in any parameterized object as an argument to a class constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, parameterized

Say I have code like this:

```
abstract class Animal[T <: Animal[T]] {
  def mateWith(that: T)
}

class Cow extends Animal[Cow] {
  override def mateWith(that: Cow) { println("cow") }
}

class Dog extends Animal[Dog] {
  override def mateWith(that: Dog) { println("dog") }
}
```

I want to write something like this:

```
class Caretaker (val pet: Animal) {
  ...
}
```

but this is invalid, since Animal needs to be parameterized.  I could solve this by parameterizing Caretaker:

```
class Caretaker[T <: Animal[T]](val pet: Animal[T]) {
  ...
}
```

but this is really unnecessary for what I'm doing.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Caretaker(val pet: Animal[_]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does the underscore mean?  Any valid parameterized type of Animal?

Comment: As far as my knowledge of scala goes, the underscore is a wildcard which in essense means "I don't care what goes here". The limitation on the parametrization of the Animal class would create the limitation on what types can effectively be passed to the Caretaker class.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want a caretaker to take care of two pets that can mate with each other, then the parameter would become important

```
class Caretaker[T <: Animal[T]](val pet1: T, val pet2: Animal[T]) {
  matePets = pet2.mateWith(pet1)
}
```